# Expected singleton: hr.employee(1, 2)

Tags: python, xml, odoo-8, odoo, qweb

Good Day! Everybody I have an error while loading the `kanban` view.  I inherit the `hr.employee` `Kanban` xml and just add a condition if a certain documents expired,  it will add a Expired Documents notification in `kanban` view, here is the xml code:

```xml
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="hr_kanban_view_employees_recruitment_kanban">
        <field name="name">HR - Employees Kanban Document Status</field>
        <field name="model">hr.employee</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.hr_kanban_view_employees"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//templates" position="before">
                <field name="employee_id"/>
                <field name="documents_status"/>
            </xpath>
            <xpath expr="//div[@class='oe_employee_details']/ul/li[@id='last_login']" position="inside">
                <span t-if="record.documents_status.raw_value" style="font-size: 100%%"
                        t-att-class="record.documents_status.raw_value==true'oe_kanban_button oe_kanban_color_3'">
                    <field name="employee_id" readonly = "1"/>
                    Has Expired Documents
                </span>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
```

and the model for `documents_status` field

and when loading

```python
documents_status = fields.Boolean('DocumentStatus', readonly = True,store = False,compute ='getdocumentStatus')

    @api.one
    def getdocumentStatus(self):
        raise Warning(self.employee_id)
        server_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(DATE_NOW.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") ,"%Y-%m-%d")
        result = {}

        for id in self.ids:
            result[id] = {
                'documents_status': True
            }
            totaldoc = self.env['hr.employee_documents'].search_count([('date_expiry', '<', server_date),('employee_doc_id','=', id)])
            if totaldoc > 0:
                result[id]['documents_status'] = True
                self.documents_status = True
            else:
                result[id]['documents_status'] = False
                self.documents_status = False
        return result
```

the `kanban` view in employee an error occurred

> Expected singleton: hr.employee(1, 2).

will someone help me with this and Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you can use api.multi instead of api.one

Comment: Ive tried it but the error still prompt

Comment: Why do you add a field named `employee_id` to the model `hr.employee`? Is it not the same as put just `id` instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know the relationship between `hr.employee` and `hr.employee_documents`. If this one is a `One2many` (many documents for a unique employee), there must be a `One2many` field in `hr.employee` model pointing to `hr.employee_documents`. Suppose this field is named `documents` (this is important to trigger the compute method through the `api.depends`). Then write this code:

```python
@api.multi
@api.depends('documents.date_expiry')
def getdocumentStatus(self):
    server_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(DATE_NOW.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), "%Y-%m-%d")
    for record in self:
        totaldoc = self.env['hr.employee_documents'].search_count([('date_expiry', '<', server_date),('employee_doc_id','=', self.id)])
        if totaldoc > 0:
            record.documents_status = True
        else:
            record.documents_status = False
```

You should write us the relationship between both models to give you an accurate answer.

Comment: Thanks for the code and the answer just rewrite my code I've still used the @api.one but I didnt used loop in the function to get the total expired documents for a specific employee :D Thanks a lot

Comment: Hello! Reading your comment, I realized that I had a mistake in the code, so I've edited my answer. I did the loop over `self`, and I was still using `self` inside this loop, instead of `record`. You can use the `@api.one` without loop and the `@api.multi` with the loop. Personally I recommend you to use `@api.multi` and the loop: it gave me less problems than `@api.one`. By the way, I'm glad I helped you. Don't forget to set the answer as correct to close the question if you think is the right one!