# Odoo 10 - understanding singleton - ValueError: Expected singleton: product.template() -

Tags: odoo

I have a custom model:

```
class ProductExtended(models.Model):
  ...
  product_id = fields.Many2one('product.template', 'Product')
  ...
```

And I am trying to do the following inside a method:

```
....
new_record.product_id = new_parametrized_product
....
```

where:

```
new_record = product.extended(1724,)
new_parametrized_product = product.template(1275,)
```

but I get:

```
ValueError: Expected Singleton: product.template()
```

Could someone help me to understand what is wrong here?

Comment: Check these links maybe it would help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31070640/valueerror-expected-singleton-odoo8 **-** https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/expected-singleton-71132 **-**  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32820727/expected-singleton-hr-employee1-2

Comment: They were, lead me to the point where this was failing.

Comment: These might be helpful to you. https://odedrabhavesh.blogspot.in/2017/02/valueerror-expected-singleton-in-odoo.html

Comment: `product_id` should be used to link to `product.product`

Answer (score -1):

The ValueError you're seeing is because somewhere you're calling something on a `product.template` that does not exist.  The expected singleton is empty in this case.

Without seeing the full stack trace of the error, it's hard to say exactly which bit is causing the error, but it's definitely because you have an empty recordset somewhere.

Comment: He's clearly getting an empty recordset, or the error would list the ids in the recordset (`Expected singleton: product.template(1,3,10)` for example).  I have definitely had this issue when calling a function on a related field that is empty, or the results of a search that return no results.  I guess it depends on the scenario and the version of Odoo you're using.  I have also seen `Boolean has no attribute field_name` type errors in certain cases.